# Segue saves data on back bar button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I've a segue on TableViewCell click, and a save button on another ViewController, it works fine on save button, but it also changes TableViewCell when i click on back bar button. How can i discard changes? There are NoteTableViewController and NoteViewController

TableViewController methods

tableView cellRowAt method

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "NoteTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NoteTableViewCell
    let note = notes[indexPath.row]

    cell.noteLabel.text = note.note

    return cell
}
```

TableViewController prepare for segue method

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let noteDetailViewController = segue.destination as! NoteViewController

        if let selectedNoteCell = sender as? NoteTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedNoteCell)!
            let selectedNote = notes[indexPath.row]
            noteDetailViewController.note = selectedNote
            noteDetailViewController.oldNote = someNote
        }
    }
}
```

This method is for saving data, it connected to saveButton of NoteViewController

```
    @IBAction func unwindToNoteList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? NoteViewController {
        let note = sourceViewController.note
        if note?.note != nil {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                notes[selectedIndexPath.row] = note!
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            } else {
                let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: notes.count, section: 0)
                notes.append(note!)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .top)
            }
            saveNotes()
        }
    }
}
```

NoteViewController methods

prepare for segue

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if saveButton === sender as? UIBarButtonItem {
        if let noteText = noteTextView.text {
            note?.note = noteText
        }
    note?.toDate = remindDate
    note?.image = photoImageView.image
    } else {
        note = oldNote
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? When you change your selected note in new view controller, it change data in cell in previous view controller, but you don't want change info in cell, right?

Comment: saves date or data?

Comment: what you do on save?

Comment: @ArtemNovichko  i don't want to change it on back bar button, but i've a save button. Question was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, by implementation NSObject copy() method. And sending a copy to NoteViewController.